# Rate Limit Pattern with Redis - Accuracy

Tags: redis, rate-limiting

### Background

I have an application that send HTTP request to foreign servers. The application communicating with other services with strict rate limit policy. For example, 5 calls per second. Any call above the allowed rate will get `429` error code.

The application is deployed in the cloud and run by multiple instances. The tasks are coming from shared queue.

The allowed rate limit synced by [Redis Rate Limit pattern](https://redislabs.com/redis-best-practices/basic-rate-limiting/).

### My current implementation

Assuming that the rate limit is 5 per second: I split the time into multiple "window". Each window has maximum rate of 5. Before each call I checking if the counter is less then 5. If yes, fire the request. If no, wait for the next window (after a second).

### The problem

In order to sync the application around the Redis, I need to Redis calls: INCR and EXPR. Let's say that each call can take around 250ms to be returned. So we have checking time of ~500ms. Having said that, in some cases you will check for old window because until you will get the answer the current second has been changed. In case that on the next second we will have another 5 quick calls - it will lead to `429` from the server.

### Question

As you can see, this pattern not really ensuring that the rate of my application will be up to 5 calls\second.

How do you recommend to do it right?

Comment: You can use multi and exec. Or I think it is best if you write a lua  script to achieve this

Comment: The lua script can return a true or false. If counter is less than 5 incr and return true. If counter is greater than 5 increment and return false. If key not present create counter set 1 then set timeout return true.

Comment: Thanks for response. lua script or not, it will just make it a little bit more accurate. Still not something that can be trusted better than the proposed solution.